# Angular 5 disable a table row

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular5

This is my HTML code for my table to display list of users:

```
<table class="table m-table m-table--head-bg-metal">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Nom
        </th>
        <th>
            Prénom
        </th>
        <th>
            Email
        </th>
        <th>
            Action
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Jhon
        </td>
        <td>
            Stone
        </td>
        <td>
            jhonStone@gmail.com
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger m-btn m-btn--icon btn-sm m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill m-btn--air" (click)="onDisableUser()">
                <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

[image]

This is typescript method:

```
onDisableUser(){
//this is the method to disable the table row..
}
```

What I want is when I click () on the action button, the **table row** will be **disabled**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whether row should be disabled or button inside td? Because all td are plain text only. Explain clearly

Comment: When I click on the button, I want to disable the whole <tr></tr>

Comment: When you disable a button it becomes non-clickable, but I don't understand what do you mean by disabling the 'row'.

Comment: @antony you can only disable the row if there are input fields .. by default there are only labels which are read only.

Comment: what do you mean by `disabled` here , are you clear with your requirements?

Comment: check this screenShot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQvO0.png

Comment: What I want is very simple: click on the button => disable the table row

Comment: Simple, on click button add css dynamically based on condition and in css simply add { pointer-events:none; opacity: 0.5}

Comment: @Srigar Thanks men ;)

here we are (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean with disable? 
If you want to remove the list item do this on the html :

```
<table class="table m-table m-table--head-bg-metal">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Nom
            </th>
            <th>
                Prénom
            </th>
            <th>
                Email
            </th>
            <th>
                Action
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngIf="!isDisable">
            <td>
                Jhon
            </td>
            <td>
                Stone
            </td>
            <td>
                jhonStone@gmail.com
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-danger m-btn m-btn--icon btn-sm m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill m-btn--air" (click)="onDisableUser()">
        <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
       </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And on the typescript:

```
  isDisable = false;

  onDisableUser(){
    this.isDisable = true;
}
```

If you want to disable it with css use this in html:

```
<tr [ngClass]="{'disabled': isDisable}>
```

Comment: this code will totally disappeared the tag
I want just to disabled 
check this screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQvO0.png

Comment: use the second option create a css class disabled and set opacity:0,5 and pointer-events:none

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css method to disable the table row.
Set the disabled to true when clicked and set the class to the `<tr>` if `disabled=true`

```css
.disable{
  cursor: not-allowed;
  }
```

```html
<table>

<tr class="disable">
  <td> akjsd </td>
</tr>

<tr >
  <td> akjsd </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

```
  isDisable = false;

  onDisableUser(){
    this.isDisable = true;
}
```